# Hot meta post conditions

Tags: support, per-site-meta, hot-questions

What conditions should be met for a meta post to appear on the Hot Meta posts list on the right side of the questions page?

E.g.:

> [image: HMP]

How many posts can be visible at one time (max 2?)? As far as I know, mods can remove posts from the Hot Meta posts list. How to check if the post was removed by a mod? Will the manually removed post be replaced with the next suitable post?

Comment: Shog answer is most likely still relevant; If not, should be edited or replaced by up-to-date answer there, so closed as dupe.